# Pandas: Change of name in columns with lambda function possible / Feedback

Tags: python, excel, pandas, lambda

After lots of help from inside here and lots of web searching I am about to finish one part (of 10) of my Cousera Datascience assignment. But as I am relative unexperienced with Python and Pandas I have the nagging feeling that the problem could have solved better.

Task: import an Excel list from here: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/environment/excel_file_tables/2013/Energy%20Indicators.xls
remove numbers and everything in with "(" in the Country name. 
rename certain country names (in dicts)

This is the code that worked. What could I have done better / more efficient?

```
energy=pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',
                 sheetname='Energy',
                 skiprows=[17],
                 skipfooter=38,
                 header=15,
                 index_col=[0],
                 usecols=[2,3,4,5]
                )

energy.index.names=['Country']
energy.rename(columns={'Renewable Electricity Production': '% Renewable'}, inplace=True)
energy=energy.reset_index()
energy.Country=energy.Country.replace(to_replace='\d',value='', regex=True)
energy.Country=energy.Country.replace(to_replace='( \()(.*)(\))',value='', regex=True)
#energy.Country=energy.Country.replace(to_replace='(\.){3}',value='None', regex=True)

dicts = {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
           "United States of America": "United States",
           "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
           "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}

for x in dicts.keys():
    energy.Country.loc[lambda s: s==x]=dicts[x]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, pandas already has a builtin function for this:

```
energy.Country.replace(dicts, inplace=True)
```